# PHP list combine similar values and count number of values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, histogram

I have a column in a MySQL database that has values such as: Value A [next row] Value B [next row] Value C [next row] Value A [next row] Value B [next row] Value C. I want each similar value to be combined and the number of times it appeared, such as: 2 (x) Value A, 2 (x) Value B, 2 (x) Value C. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a histogram.  You should perform a query like:

```
select value, count(*) as count from table group by value
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05375/2) demonstrating the database query

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more... I'm not sure how I can do what I described with the info you put in the comment... sorry! Thank you so much!

Comment: @David I put up an SQLFiddle showing the result for a simple test case